# Chaincode problem in Hyperledger fabric network

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I made a custom network in Hyperledger fabric with TLS enabled, I can able to successfully create channels and join peers into channel.

But currently I am facing a problem:

1. Problem in chaincode commands.

When I tried to execute the below command

- **peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled**

Error i got in the console:  **failed to endorse proposal: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing**

And the peer0.org1.example.com container exited after this, logs shows below

```
Version: 1.4.3
 Commit SHA: b8c4a6a
 Go version: go1.11.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.15
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2021-02-17 06:14:54.102 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2021-02-17 06:14:54.105 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2021-02-17 06:14:54.345 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
2021-02-17 06:14:54.549 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 005 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect: connection refused
2021-02-17 06:14:54.676 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 006 Retrying couchdb request in 250ms. Attempt:2  Error:Get http://couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect: connection refused
2021-02-17 06:14:54.930 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 007 Retrying couchdb request in 500ms. Attempt:3  Error:Get http://couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect: connection refused
2021-02-17 06:14:55.432 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 008 Retrying couchdb request in 1s. Attempt:4  Error:Get http://couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect: connection refused
2021-02-17 06:14:56.438 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 009 Retrying couchdb request in 2s. Attempt:5  Error:Get http://couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect: connection refused
2021-02-17 06:14:58.445 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 00a Retrying couchdb request in 4s. Attempt:6  Error:Get http://couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect: connection refused
2021-02-17 06:15:02.939 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 00b Created state database _users
2021-02-17 06:15:03.063 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 00c Created state database _replicator
2021-02-17 06:15:03.064 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 00d ledger mgmt initialized
2021-02-17 06:15:03.064 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00e Auto-detected peer address: 172.18.0.12:7051
2021-02-17 06:15:03.065 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00f Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2021-02-17 06:15:03.065 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 010 Auto-detected peer address: 172.18.0.12:7051
2021-02-17 06:15:03.065 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 011 Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2021-02-17 06:15:03.096 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 012 Starting peer with TLS enabled
2021-02-17 06:15:03.097 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 013 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org1.example.com
2021-02-17 06:15:03.097 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 014 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7052
2021-02-17 06:15:03.099 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 015 system chaincode lscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) registered
2021-02-17 06:15:03.099 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 016 system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
2021-02-17 06:15:03.099 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 017 system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) registered
2021-02-17 06:15:03.099 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 018 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle,true) disabled
2021-02-17 06:15:03.101 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO 019 Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0.org1.example.com:7051 and bootstrap set [peer1.org1.example.com:8051]
2021-02-17 06:15:03.104 UTC [gossip.gossip] NewGossipService -> INFO 01a Creating gossip service with self membership of Endpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, PKI-ID: 452f291d782b4158adc9b146d53ebc80be2bb8240ba0ffe848d6e35208525834, Metadata: 
2021-02-17 06:15:03.104 UTC [gossip.gossip] start -> INFO 01b Gossip instance peer0.org1.example.com:7051 started
2021-02-17 06:15:03.105 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01c system chaincode lscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2021-02-17 06:15:03.105 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 01d Init CSCC
2021-02-17 06:15:03.105 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01e system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2021-02-17 06:15:03.106 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 01f Init QSCC
2021-02-17 06:15:03.106 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 020 system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed
2021-02-17 06:15:03.106 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 021 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle) disabled
2021-02-17 06:15:03.106 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 022 Deployed system chaincodes
2021-02-17 06:15:03.107 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 023 Created with config TLS: true, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000
2021-02-17 06:15:03.107 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 024 Discovery service activated
2021-02-17 06:15:03.107 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 025 Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer0.org1.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org1.example.com:7051]
2021-02-17 06:15:03.108 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 026 Started peer with ID=[name:"peer0.org1.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org1.example.com:7051]
2021-02-17 06:15:03.111 UTC [kvledger] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 027 Loading prereset height from path [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains]
2021-02-17 06:15:03.111 UTC [fsblkstorage] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 028 Loading Pre-reset heights
2021-02-17 06:15:03.111 UTC [fsblkstorage] preRestHtFiles -> INFO 029 Dir [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains] missing... exiting
2021-02-17 06:15:03.111 UTC [fsblkstorage] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 02a Pre-reset heights loaded
2021-02-17 06:15:03.112 UTC [nodeCmd] func7 -> INFO 02b Starting profiling server with listenAddress = 0.0.0.0:6060
2021-02-17 06:15:06.110 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 02c Could not connect to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
2021-02-17 06:15:13.171 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02d TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.1:35634
2021-02-17 06:15:14.183 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02e TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.1:35638
2021-02-17 06:15:15.551 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02f TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.1:35642
2021-02-17 06:15:34.112 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 030 Could not connect to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
2021-02-17 06:15:53.633 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 031 [][de5a8ae1] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
2021-02-17 06:15:53.634 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 032 [][de5a8ae1] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (1ms)
2021-02-17 06:15:53.634 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 033 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.1:35662 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.926352ms
2021-02-17 06:16:02.129 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 034 Could not connect to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
2021-02-17 06:16:30.134 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 035 Could not connect to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x68 pc=0xd9fae7]

goroutine 319 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc.(*LifeCycleSysCC).ChaincodeDefinition(0xc002104a50, 0xc002462ee0, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc002104a00, 0xc002462ee0, 0xa, 0xc002420f00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc/lscc.go:187 +0x37
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).GetChaincodeDefinition(0xc002160720, 0xc002462ee0, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0020c6e50, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:152 +0x64
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal(0xc00024c840, 0xc00241cd90, 0xc002474b40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:228 +0xd65
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal(0xc00024c840, 0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0xc002474690, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:500 +0x3c9
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal(0xc00215f490, 0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0xc002474690, 0x10c0c60, 0xc002435700, 0x7f70da61e2c8)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61 +0x8f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal(0xc00215f450, 0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0xc002474690, 0xc00215f450, 0xc00237be00, 0xc002420d80)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32 +0x51
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0x0, 0xc00230d318, 0x42be22, 0xc000000008)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:169 +0x86
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0x0, 0x18, 0xc000061500, 0xc000061500)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:31 +0x118
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor(0xc00022bb60, 0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0xc002492200, 0xc0024746e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/throttle.go:54 +0xd3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor-fm(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0xc002492200, 0xc0024746e0, 0xc00246f260, 0xc0024359fe, 0x126db79, 0x16)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:228 +0x73
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0x0, 0x13d5bfe, 0xc002435950, 0x1020220)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34 +0x9f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435950, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0xc002492200, 0xc0024746e0, 0xc0002ef980, 0x4a0076, 0x602cb4c2, 0x2fe8f619)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:91 +0x256
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435800, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0x13c0540, 0x1ff3648, 0x11b8d60, 0xc002490101)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34 +0x9f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435800, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0xc002492200, 0xc0024746e0, 0x10b2980, 0x1ff3648, 0xc0002efae8, 0x40d1d8)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:30 +0x1d6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1(0x13d5b80, 0xc002435800, 0x11bcd60, 0xc002474690, 0xc002492200, 0xc002492220, 0x10b2980, 0x1ff3648, 0x1226540, 0xc002374700)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:39 +0x153
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler(0x10c0c60, 0xc00215f450, 0x13d5b80, 0xc002435800, 0xc00241cbd0, 0xc0003b36b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc002374700, 0x50)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:171 +0x158
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc0001a8480, 0x13dd600, 0xc002284c00, 0xc002374700, 0xc00227d680, 0x1ed38c0, 0xc0024357a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:982 +0x4cd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc0001a8480, 0x13dd600, 0xc002284c00, 0xc002374700, 0xc0024357a0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1208 +0x1311
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1(0xc0024627d0, 0xc0001a8480, 0x13dd600, 0xc002284c00, 0xc002374700)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686 +0x9f
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:684 +0xa1
```

**docker-compose-base file**

```
version: '2'

services:

  orderer1.example.com:
    container_name: orderer1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
  
  orderer2.example.com:
    container_name: orderer2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
  
  orderer3.example.com:
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 9050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:9051

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 10051:10051
```

Comment: please upload the full log to some website like pastebin

Comment: @yacovm thanks for your response, Now I have to added the full logs in the question.

Comment: You're using "peer lifecycle queryinstalled" but that's a Fabric v2 command and your peer is Fabric 1.4.3

Comment: In any case, open a JIRA in jira.hyperledger.org/ because this is probably a bug, but since the version of Fabric is pretty old (1.4.3) I am not sure it exists in the latest Fabric version of 1.4.10

Comment: @yacovm Thank you so much. I haven't noticed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Yacov said, you are targeting a v2.x lifecycle command against a v1.4.x peer, therefore an error is expected. When I tried the same thing on latest v1.4.10 peer, I get the following error back:

```
Error: query failed with status: 500 - make sure the chaincode _lifecycle has been successfully instantiated and try again: could not get definition for chaincode _lifecycle without a ledger context
```

This makes sense since v2.x lifecycle uses a system chaincode in _lifecycle namespace. It doesn't exist on a v1.4.x peer and therefore you get the error. Perhaps the error wasn't handled properly back in v1.4.3. You should upgrade to v1.4.10 regardless because there are many critical fixes since v1.4.3 timeframe.

Comment: Yeah, just got to know about it. Thanks for the solution...Dave